# LINE Notifyを使ったPythonアプリをherokuに公開したが、勝手に実行されるのはなぜ？

Tags: python, python3, heroku, line

webからスクレイピングした情報をLINE Notifyを使って通知するPythonアプリをherokuに公開しました。

スケジューラーを使ってもいないのに、定期的に実行されて、Lineに通知が来ます。

herokuの仕様なのでしょうか。

プランはfreeプランです。
herokuのfreeプランは再起動をすると聞いたことがあります。

再起動のタイミングでmain.pyが実行されているのでしょうか。

コードを追加しました。(main.py)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

r = requests.get("*************")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

css1 = soup.find_all("p", class_ = "top-text")
t_text = css1[0].getText()


msg = t_text

LINE_TOKEN =  "****************"
LINE_NOTIFY_URL = "*******************"

def send_jt_information(msg):
    method = "POST"
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % LINE_TOKEN}
    payload = {"message": msg}
    try:
        payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode("utf-8")
        req = urllib.request.Request(
            url=LINE_NOTIFY_URL, data=payload, method=method, headers=headers)
        urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Exception Error: ", e)
        sys.exit(1)

def main():
    send_jt_information(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ソースコードを示すことは可能ですか？

Comment: コードを追加しました。6時間に1回Lineに通知が来ます。

Answer (score 1):

公式のドキュメントのこのあたりが参考になるのではないでしょうか。

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting

> Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem will be deleted. The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time). Manual restarts (heroku ps:restart) and releases (deploys or changing config vars) will reset this 24 hour period.

質問者さんの場合は 6 時間ごとにとのことですが、 at least once per day とあるので、正確に何時間ごとに restart されるかというのは仕様としては明示されてはいないようです。

Comment: 気になる点は2点。①再起動されることで公開されているpyファイルが都度実行されてしまうのか。②ドキュメントを見ると24時間に1回程度という表現から6回は多いきがする。（freeプランだからか）herokuの仕様ならしょうがないが改善できるならしたい。